# Build error after disabling the address sanitizer in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I have been using the address sanitizer in Xcode for a couple of weeks to debug a few problems, and finally decide to turn it off again. But after I unchecked it and tried to build it gives me these four errors:

```
error build: Undefined symbol: ___ubsan_handle_add_overflow
error build: Undefined symbol: ___ubsan_handle_nonnull_arg
error build: Undefined symbol: ___ubsan_handle_pointer_overflow
error build: Undefined symbol: ___ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1
```

If I go ahead and enable the address sanitizer again it builds.

Any idea how to solve this, or what cause it?

[image]

I have tried to clean the build folder and delete derived data, but I get the same errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve it. As you can see on the image in my question, the "Undefined Behavior Sanitizer" was still turned on, but greyed out, so I tried disabling it by editing the `.xcscheme` file directly.

To do so, right click your `.xcodeproj` file and select "Show package content" and inside the `xcshareddata/xcschemes` folder you will find the `.xcscheme` file. Open it in a code editor and edit: `enableUBSanitizer = "YES"` to `enableUBSanitizer = "NO"`

Save and you are good to go!